# Having some problems using filter() to remove an element from DOM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Having some issues targeting the correct element from the DOM after an ajax call succeeds. What I have now is this in my view:

```
@foreach($tags as $tag)
    <div class="skillLabel deleteSkill">    
        <h4>
            <button class="btn btn-primary removeTag" data-id="{{ $tag->id }}">
                <a href="">x</a>
                <span class="label">{{ $tag->tag_name }}</span>
            </button>
        </h4>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And in my jQuery:

```
//AJAX Handling
var base_url = 'http://localhost:8000';
var tagID = $(this).data("id");
$('.removeTag').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"/people/removeTag",

        data:{
            userID: <?php echo $user->id; ?>,
            tagID: tagID
        },

        type: "POST",

        dataType: "text", 

        success: function(  ) {
            $(".removeTag").filter(FILTER BY WHERE DATA ID MATCHES TAG ID).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

I want that particular tag to disappear upon success (which the ajax request is working). Also, just curious (separate issue, but may as well ask), if I have a ton of modal windows loading at the top of the page and and are triggered using buttons, would it be quicker to have those be ajax calls?

**EDIT**:

Here is the HTML once rendered:

```
<div class="skillLabel deleteSkill">    
    <h4>
        <button class="btn btn-primary removeTag" data-id="6">
            <a href="">x</a>
            <span class="label">New</span>
        </button>
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="skillLabel deleteSkill">    
    <h4>
        <button class="btn btn-primary removeTag" data-id="14">
            <a href="">x</a>
            <span class="label">Test</span>
        </button>
    </h4>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

Better yet, is there a way I could remove the `div` containing the tags? I feel like it would be as easy as locating that button, and removing its parent elements.

Comment: so basically, you want to remove the parent div of the element you just clicked ?

Comment: Essentially. My first step was to remove the button, but ultimately, I will need to remove the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, if i understood your problem correctly:

```
//AJAX Handling
var base_url = 'http://localhost:8000';
var tagID = $(this).data("id");
$('.removeTag').click(function() {
    var button = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"/people/removeTag",

        data:{
            userID: <?php echo $user->id; ?>,
            tagID: tagID
        },

        type: "POST",

        dataType: "text", 

        success: function(  ) {
            //If you want to remove just the button:
            button.remove();
            //Or this if you want to delete the whole div:
            button.parents('.deleteSkill').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(".removeTag").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("id") == tagID;
}).remove();
```

**Note**: this uses `.data("id")` instead of `.attr("id")` from the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You would need this:

```
$(".removeTag").filter(function(){
     return $(this).attr("id") == tagID;
}).remove();
```

Comment: Hmm... it's deleting all of my classes of .removeTag, not just the one with the data-id.

Comment: AminJafari yeah that would work too. @AustinSlominski show the formed html and ask what you want clearly

Answer (score 0):

- You can filter elements by their `data-id` using `[data-id=""]` inside jQuery selector.
- For removing `div` which contains element, you can use `.closest('div')`.

So, finally:

```
$('.removeTag[data-id="' + tagID + '"]').closest('div').remove();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/4aoeg61h/1/).

Comment: @AustinSlominski Have you seen fiddle that I provided? It actually removes required `div`s. And what version of jQuery do you use?